# Shell use value from for loop to set files' name

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to use Shell to run my Python script and use the variable from for loop to name my output file

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
setsid python main.py 1>data/$i$_logfile.txt 2>&1
done
```

But I got `1.txt` not `1_logfile.txt`. How can I do it successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `_` is a valid character for a variable name, you need to use the `${varname}` syntax to let the shell know the end of the variable name. Otherwise, you have `$i` and `$_logfile` as variables, but the latter is empty.

The syntax `$i$` does not exist.

Use:

```
setsid python main.py 1>data/${i}_logfile.txt 2>&1
```

---

> Note that **$variable** is actually a simplified form of **${variable}**. In contexts where the **$variable** syntax causes an error, the longer form may work. ([via](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varsubn.html))